# Understanding the past growth of an ETF

Tags: etf, index-fund, vanguard, market-indexes

I'm trying to understand the grow of an ETF (`Vanguard VOO`) over the past year.

I have checked both the Vanguard web page and Google, for the same ETF, and they show massive different growths.

In Google (search `Vanguard VOO market price`), the market price of `VOO` starts at 268 and finishes at 271.26. That's a growth of 1.1% approx.

The Vanguard's web page (https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/performance/voo) reports a growth of 4.25%.

I'm definitely overlooking something, what is it?

Comment: Past performance is not terribly valuable to look at, *anyway*.  Except comparing a fund with its index.   In that, VOO should be breathtakingly close to the S&P 500

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The currently accepted [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/115318/64920) is incorrect.

Vanguard is quoting the 1-year return as of 9/30/2019. This is calculated from the close of 9/28/2018 (the last trading day of September 2018) to the close of 9/30/2019.

It is important to get the exact dates right because stock indices can easily rise or fall 1% or more in a day. Stock price fluctuations are rough, not smooth, and a day's return can be a significant portion of a year's return. This is a counterintuitive property of Brownian motion.

VOO close on 9/28/2018 was $267.05. VOO close on 9/30/2019 was $272.60. As Bob Baerker notes, dividends over that span totaled $5.43. The exact total return depends on the prices at which the dividends were reinvested, but these numbers are consistent with a little over 4% return. Yahoo lists the adjusted close on 9/28/2018 as $261.52, and $272.60/$261.52 = 1.0424.

Comment: I mentioned that Vanguard's numbers were different because they probably used a slightly different start/end date.  But you picked up on the other reason, namely that the dividend reinvestment on on various dates changes the ROI slightly.

Answer (score 9):

Google's numbers:

- 10/01/18 $268.04
- 09/27/19 $271.26

That's a gain of 1.20% which is far less than the actual return because Google  did not account for dividends.

During that period you would have received $5.43 in dividends so the Total Return with dividends reinvested would have been 3.34%.  You can verify these numbers with a DRIP calculator or with the adjusted close numbers at Yahoo Finance.

Vanguard's numbers are probably higher because their 1 year calculation used a start date a few days before or after these numbers.

Comment: This is why it's a bad idea to accept an answer so quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing two different data points.

The Vanguard page you linked lists 4.25% as the 1-year return in a table under the following heading:

> Average annual returns—updated monthly

This means that the *average of the returns of 1-year periods during the life of the fund* are 4.25%.

Google lists the price 1 year ago as 268, and today as 271, indicating that *the return for this past year* is closer to 1%.

Your Vanguard number is an aggregate of your Google number and other data (all prior years, at least some of which had higher returns).

Comment: The "other data" probably includes dividends.  If you click the  "1 Year" performance button, $10,000 a year ago should now be worth $10,424.75.

Comment: No, 4.25%  is the return for the past one year.  The average annual return since inception is 13.44%.  And no, the Vanguard number is NOT an aggregate of your Google number and other data (all prior years, at least some of which had higher returns).

Comment: -1: Absolutely not. What "average annual returns" means is that for periods longer than 1 year, the returns are *annualized* (technically, it's the compound annual growth rate). Each number pertains to a single period of the specified duration ending on the specified date (9/30/2019). The closest thing to an "average of the returns of 1-year periods during the life of the fund" is the number under "Since inception", not the number under "1-year".

Comment: I almost never DV, but we need to highlight that this accepted answer is incorrect.  Plus, I do believe a highly downvoted answer that is accepted will reward an achievement!